# Get respond from api with retrofit2 And Rx

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

I used Retrofit with Rx to send a request and get JSON from API.
Everything looks fine but When I want to access to the JSON Array it couldn't work.

```
public class Device {
private boolean current;
private String uid;

public boolean isCurrent() {
    return current;
}

public void setCurrent(boolean current) {
    this.current = current;
}

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public void setUid(String uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}
}
```

---

```
public class DeviceResult {
private ArrayList<Device> devices;

public ArrayList<Device> getDevices() {
    return devices;
}

public void setDevices(ArrayList<Device> devices) {
this.devices = devices; } }
```

---

You can see the `DeviceResult` class that there is an ArrayList named `devices`

```
public interface TokenApi {
    @GET("devices")
    Observable<Response<DeviceResult>> getDeviceId(@Header("Authorization") 
    String token);
    }
```

---

The `deviceResults.isSuccessful()` is true and I saw my Respond from the Okhttp log but `deviceResults.body()` is not what i expect.

```
 RetrofitHelper retrofitHelper = new RetrofitHelper("http://172.16.16.16");
    TokenApi tokenApi = retrofitHelper.getService(TokenApi.class);
    rx.Observable<Response<DeviceResult>> listObservable = tokenApi.getDeviceId("Bearer" + " " + getToken());
    listObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(deviceResults -> {
        if (deviceResults.isSuccessful()) {
// isSuccessful is true
// the problem is body tell me some dumy thing
            Log.i("Devices_body", deviceResults.body().toString());
            Log.i("Devices_message", deviceResults.message());
        }

    }, throwable -> Log.i("Error get devices", throwable.toString()));
```

my JSON Array

```
{
"devices": [
    {
        "agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36",
        "browser": "Chrome",
        "current": false,
        "deviceType": "Desktop",
        "id": 9848,
        "ip": "172.16.106.40",
        "lastAccessTime": 1527337813000,
        "os": "Win10",
        "osVersion": "10.0",
        "uid": "f3fcf0845df6e83cd150e86aadc37206"
    },
    {
        "agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0",
        "browser": "Firefox",
        "browserVersion": "59",
        "current": true,
        "deviceType": "Desktop",
        "id": 9828,
        "ip": "172.16.106.44",
        "lastAccessTime": 1527066972000,
        "os": "Win10",
        "osVersion": "10.0",
        "uid": "3d943476a879dcf609f79a5ec736bedc"
    },
}
```

> The **problem** is that `deviceResults.body().toString()` doesn't get me
>   the JSON but I saw the Okhttp log that the respond of the request is
>   working fine!

Comment: Please use only "deviceResults.body()". May be it works.

Comment: No, it's not work

Comment: ok.let me check again

Comment: you were right the `body()` is ok but now i dont know how to get devices from it. idont even know that what is the type of `deviceResults.body()`. @saurabh-vadhva

Comment: Just pass that body to JSONObject like this JSONObject json = new JSONObject(deviceResults.body()); And get the devices from "json" object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that i just saw the Debugger and understand that the respons (`deviceResults.body()`) is getting me the `ArrayList<Device>` and i didn't need to parse it to `JSONObject`.

Answer (score 0):

You must create the POJO class for your response using this link.
After that try to apply GsonConvertorFactory

```
dependencies {  
// Retrofit & OkHttp
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'

// JSON Converter
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
```

}

**Then try to converting Response Array or Object to JSON.**